# angular Uncaught ReferenceError: Service is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-services

I have the following component in which I am trying to inject a service:

```
angular.
  module('phoneList').
  component('phoneList', {
    templateUrl: '/static/common/angular/phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
    controller: ['$http', 'authenticationService',
      function PhoneListController($http, authenticationService) {
        var self = this;


          authenticationService.authenticate().then(function(){
                console.log('it worked!!!!!!!!');
                }); 

      }
    ]
  });
```

The service looks like this:

```
angular.module('authentication').factory('authenticationService', function($http, $se){
    function authenticate(){

        $http.post('/o/token/', data, config)
              .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  console.log('auth service: '+data['access_token']);
                  $sessionStorage.access_token = data['access_token'];
              });
    }    
    function getToken(){
        return $sessionStorage.access_token;
    }
    return {
        authenticate:authenticate,
        getToken:getToken
    };
});
```

My phone-list.module.js looks like this:

```
angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'phoneList',
  'authentication',
]);

angular.module('phoneList', ['authentication']);
```

When I run this i get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: authenticationService is not defined

When I put 'authenticationService' in '', I get the error:

> Error [$injector:unpr] authtenticationService

Comment: @A1rPun I tried that and I get the same error.

Comment: You are defining `angular.module('phonecatApp')` twice which implies you want to create the module twice which is not possible. There is also an error in your error `authtenticationService` (maybe typo?).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the service isn't properly injected into the PhoneListController.

Change it to:

```
controller: ['$http', 'authenticationService',
  function PhoneListController($http, authenticationService) {
...
```

The strings in the array are just to keep the injected dependency references minification safe. The service still needs to be added as a function argument.

Also be sure to call `angular.module` *once* for each component:

app.module.js

```
angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phoneList',
  'authentication',
]);
```

phone-list.module.js

```
angular.module('phoneList', ['authentication']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Oberon.  I get the error still:  Error [$injector:unpr] authtenticationService.  Do I need to add  authtenticationService to my module dependency instead of 'authentication'?

Comment: I would follow @A1rPun suggestion and define the `phoneList` and `phonecatApp` modules only _once_. I'll edit my answer with a possible alternative.

Comment: I did that as well and I get the same error. Thanks again for your help.