# AngularJS - Service is not defined error in function but fine in controller - ReferenceError: systemService is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm really new to AngularJS so this might be really obvious!

I've got a service which does some basic checks and then returns the information. I call this service in a controller and in a function.

When I call it in the controller it works fine without an error.

When I call it in the function I get

> angular.js:9101 ReferenceError: systemService is not defined

**Call to service in Controller that works:**

```
myApp.controller('continueController', ["$scope", "$rootScope", 'systemService', function ($scope, $rootScope, systemService) {
            $scope.ContinueAngularMethod = function () {

                $rootScope.field = 'payment';
                $scope.field = $rootScope.field;
                $scope.notApp = '1';
                console.log("I don't error in here");
                $scope.ss = systemService.checkDropDownValue($scope.payment.type, $scope.notApp);
                $rootScope.$apply();
            }
        }]);
```

**Call to service in function that doesn't work:**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

                $scope.changeme = function () {
                    console.log("Drop down changes ideally do something here....");

                    //Call to service  
                    $scope.ss = systemService.checkDropDownValue($scope.payment.type, $scope.notApp);

                    console.log($scope.ss.field);
                    console.log($scope.ss.notAppJ);

                }
```

**This is my code in full:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

        //Angular stuff
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

        //Set up my service
        myApp.service('systemService', function () {

            this.info = {}; //Declaring the object

            this.checkDropDownValue = function (type, notAppJ) {


                if (type != 'PayPal') {
                    console.log("I am not PayPal");
                    field = 'other'
                    notApp = '0';
                }
                else if (type == 'PayPal' && notApp == '1') {
                    console.log("i am in the else if - functionality later");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("i am in the else - functionality later");
                }

                this.info.field = type;
                this.info.number = notApp;

                return this.info;
            };

        });

        myApp.controller('continueController', ["$scope", "$rootScope", 'systemService', function ($scope, $rootScope, systemService) {
            $scope.ContinueAngularMethod = function () {

                $rootScope.field = 'payment';
                $scope.field = $rootScope.field;
                $scope.notApp = '1';
                console.log("I don't error in here");
                $scope.ss = systemService.checkDropDownValue($scope.payment.type, $scope.notApp);
                $rootScope.$apply();
            }
        }]);

        function MyCtrl($scope) {

            $scope.changeme = function () {
                console.log("Drop down changes ideally do something here....");

                //Call to service  
                $scope.ss = systemService.checkDropDownValue($scope.payment.type, $scope.notApp);

                console.log($scope.ss.field);
                console.log($scope.ss.notAppJ);

            }

            $scope.myFunct = function (keyEvent) {

            if (keyEvent.which === 13) {
                //They hit the enter key so ignore this 
                keyEvent.preventDefault();
            }

            //Becauase a new child scope is generated you can't use $scope as that refers to the parent . But this refers to the child. 
            var rPromise = findAll(this.softwareText);

            }
        }

    </script>
```

I tried these without any luck:

[angular Uncaught ReferenceError: Service is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440866/angular-uncaught-referenceerror-service-is-not-defined)

[AngularJS - ReferenceError: $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773161/angularjs-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

[Initialize $scope variables for multiple controllers - AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921071/initialize-scope-variables-for-multiple-controllers-angularjs)

Comment: what is `MyCtrl`?  that's not a controller, it's just a random function.  Where is it called from?

Comment: It's defined in my HTML as `<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">`

Comment: that won't work;  as I already mentioned, `MyCtrl` isn't a controller.

Comment: Ok - can I only call a service from a controller? Not a function? So to fix it should I put a call into a controller which will then call my service? Or is there a more direct way?

Comment: You must be using an older version of Angular if `MyCtrl` is declared this way and actually functions, this declaration style was removed in Angular 1.3.  Aside from that, you can't use `systemService` inside that function because it isn't declared, and wasn't injected.

Comment: @Claies I see - thanks - I'll update my angular version!

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of defining the `MyCtrl` is deprecated, you need angular to inject the systemService depedency in order to use it.

Try defining the MyCtrl controller the same way you defined `continueController`, like this:

```
    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ["$scope", 'systemService', function ($scope, systemService) {
        $scope.changeme = function () {
            console.log("Drop down changes ideally do something here....");

            //Call to service  
            $scope.ss = systemService.checkDropDownValue($scope.payment.type, $scope.notApp);

            console.log($scope.ss.field);
            console.log($scope.ss.notAppJ);

        }

        $scope.myFunct = function (keyEvent) {

        if (keyEvent.which === 13) {
            //They hit the enter key so ignore this 
            keyEvent.preventDefault();
        }

        //Becauase a new child scope is generated you can't use $scope as that refers to the parent . But this refers to the child. 
        var rPromise = findAll(this.softwareText);

        }
    }]);
```

Comment: That solved it! Thank you! I'll mark as the correct answer when the time limit runs out!

Answer (score 1):

MyCtrl shoud provide dependency to `systemService` with [$inject property](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation) like

```
function MyCtrl($scope, systemService) {

}

MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'systemService']
```